# Python/Flask. How can include multiple forms on a single view.py file

Tags: python, html, flask, flask-wtforms

I am developing a python web application using the Flask framework. The application has several forms namely: The login form, the registration form, check balance form, withdraw cash form, and transfer money form. I have a single **view.py** file that i intend to use to render all these forms like this:

```
###login form
    @app.route('/login', methods = ['POST'])
    def login():
        form = LoginForm()
        if request.method == 'POST':
          if form.validate() == False:
             flash('pin is required.')
          else:
             return render_template('index.html')
        elif request.method == 'GET':
             return render_template('login.html', form = form)

    ##withdraw cash
    @app.route('/withdrawCash', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def withdrawCash():
        form = withdrawCashForm()
          if request.method == 'POST':...

    ##transfer cash
    @app.route('/transferCash', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def transferCash():
        form = transferCashForm()
          if request.method == 'POST':......etc
```

Is this possible to have one view file rendering all these forms or should i have view files for each form?

Comment: You write a `)` after `form.amount`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @stamaimer  after removing the ")" from withdrawcash.html  i now get a new error saying `UndefinedError: 'form' is undefined`. Any hints on what is wrong with my approach?

Comment: The template file `withdrawCash.html` need a form. But you didn't pass a form to it in the view function `withdrawCash `.

Comment: when i include `form = withdrawCash()`  on views.py  i get the error `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`...very frustrating i must confess

Comment: I think the name of form class must be `WithdrawCash ` instead of `withdrawCash `. `withdrawCash` is the name of view function.

Comment: Still no success...now i get the following error `NameError: global name 'WithdrawCash' is not defined`

Comment: I think the code is written by someone else instead of you.

Comment: It is my beginners code and thats the reason for posting this question because i cannot trace where the bug is

Answer (score 0):

The question above has been edited. I initially thought i had gone around the problem but after reviewing the problem it is clear that whatever answer i had provided was wrong.